# Area between curves involving $e$

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse, area

Find the area of the region bounded by the curve $ y= e^x$, the coordinate axes, and the line $x=2$

Can you tell me what is wrong with my solution?

$$\int_0^2 e^x \,dx =7.38\dots - 1 = 6.38\dots$$

Comment: looks good why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: This is correct, your integral evaluates to $e^2 - e^0 = e^2 - 1 = 7.38\ldots - 1 = 6.38\ldots$. You might want to mention the antiderivative of $e^x$ before you plug in values.

Answer (score 1):

You are right
$$A=\int_{0}^{2} e^{x} dx=e^2-1.$$